# Need help on variable conversion and adding a “\” to an existing variable value

Tags: c++, variables

I must replace the hard-coded "NT Authority\" with a LPTSTR variable named DomainName.

"DomainName" contain the correct "NT Authority" detected from the system.

The problem is I'm unable to adapt it to the code due to my lack of knowledge in c++ (I'm most familiar with VB.NET)

Note: DomainName need to have a "\" added too on its variable value because its value (on English system) is "NT Authority" and need to be "NT Authority\"

Thanks in advance for your time and efforts.

Here is a part of the code:

```
// Second call to LookupAccountSid to get the account name.
LookupAccountSid(
NULL,                   // name of local or remote computer
pSidOwner,              // security identifier
AcctName,               // account name buffer
(LPDWORD)&dwAcctName,   // size of account name buffer 
DomainName,             // domain name
(LPDWORD)&dwDomainName, // size of domain name buffer
&eUse);                 // SID type                  

try
{
    CString name = GetTokenUser(hToken);
    const wchar_t arg[] = L"NT AUTHORITY\\";

    if(0 == _wcsnicmp(name, arg, sizeof(arg)/sizeof(arg[0])-1))
    {                   
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return hToken;
    }
 }
 catch(...)
 {
    _ASSERT(0);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compare, the data types should be equal:

```
CString name = GetTokenUser(hToken);
const CString key = L"NT AUTHORITY\\";
if (name == key)
{
  //...
}
```

You may want to convert `name` to all upper case before the comparison.  Check the methods of CString.

If there is an issue, you should use the wide character version of CString.  I'm not sure if this Microsoft abomination automatically adjusts when you compiler for multibyte or UTF character sets.

Comment: Thanks this leaded me to the solution.